# Is it reasonable to think charge as an energy carrier? Why?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electric-current, charge, voltage

I learned in physics that potential difference is the work done on unit positive charge going from the point of lower potential to the point of higher potential. And electromotive force is the energy transferred per unit charge when one type of energy is converted into electrical energy.

So I came up with idea that I can think a charge as an energy carrier. The EMF gives energy to a charge and the charge transports the energy to somewhere else.

I am wondering is this analogy reasonable? And why?

Answer (score 2):

> The EMF gives energy to a charge and the charge transports the energy to somewhere else.

This is not usually the case. In most cases the energy is transported in the fields, not in the charges.

For example, consider an ordinary light switch and light bulb. The charges move at rates of a couple of mm/s, so if the light bulb were located a couple of meters away from the switch then, if the charges carried the energy, it would take around 1000 s (~20 min) for the light bulb to turn on after you flip the switch. And even that would require a DC power supply. An AC power supply would never turn on since the charges move less than 1 mm before turning around and moving back.

In contrast, when you flip the switch, the change in the fields propagates along the wires at a large fraction of the speed of light. And the energy transport in those fields goes along the wire at that speed regardless of the slow motion of the charges.

As you get further into your studies, you will be introduced to Poynting's theorem, which is the primary theorem regarding energy transport and conservation in electromagnetism. In that theorem, there is only one term that involves charge. That is the term that governs the work done on matter by the fields. So the charges are not responsible for energy transport, but they are critical for energy conversion. They are what allow the energy to be converted from electromagnetic field energy to some form of energy in the matter (thermal energy, kinetic energy, mechanical energy, chemical energy, etc.)

Comment: @ Dale sir I'm having some confusion regarding the paragraph no. 2 in which you are telling that it would take around 20 minutes etc. So but as soon as we put the potential difference across the ends of the wire at that instant the electric fields tends to form inside the conductor and if the electric field is formed then all the electrons will get disturbed across the current carrying wire which are located near the bulb as well so they don't have to travel much distance to get into the bulb and the bulb will start to glow so isn't the OP's statement comes out to be true here?

Comment: .....Because all the electrons will flow like the water flows inside the wire, please explain this to us.

Comment: @TejasDahake yes, there are electrons that don’t have to travel far to get to the bulb, but we need energy to travel to the bulb. It would take 20 min (with DC) for the energized electrons to reach the bulb and replace the deenergized ones. If the charges transport the energy then the energy transport happens at the speed the charges move